# Spring request parameter parsing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller, spring-web

Can someone please explain the following behaviour:

Given the following HTTP GET request
`/test?q=queryString&map[one]=val&map[two]=val2&map[three]=val3`

why does this `Controller` method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public ResponseEntity<Void> test(String q, Map<String, String> map) {
    log.info("Q: " + q);
    log.info("Map: " + map);

    return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
}
```

result in

```
Q: queryString
Map: {}
```

whereas if I wrap both parameters in a so-aptly named `Wrapper` class

```
public class Wrapper {

    private String q;

    private Map<String, String> map;

    //getters & setters
}
```

and refactor the `Controller` method so

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public ResponseEntity<Void> test(Wrapper wrapper) {
    log.info("Q: " + wrapper.getQ());
    log.info("Map: " + wrapper.getMap());

    return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
}
```

the result is as follows:

```
Q: queryString
Map: {one=val, two=val2, three=val3}
```

Why does **Spring** only bind the `map` variable values if it's contained inside a wrapper object?

**EDIT**

Looking at `@RequestParam` [JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) it states

> **If the method parameter is `Map<String, String>` or `MultiValueMap<String, String>` and a parameter name is not specified, then the map parameter is populated with all request parameter names and values.**

But adding `@RequestParam(name = "map")` to the `map` variable doesn't change anything. It's still empty.

Comment: Did you try `public ResponseEntity<Void> test(@RequestParam String q, @RequestParam Map<String, String> map) {...` as well? It states "...and a parameter name is **not** specified...". Just a guess...

Comment: Yes, I did. Doesn't do squat, `map` is still empty.